# Fetching data from mongo-tracker in ' Rasa' and storing it in mongoDB at runtime like sender_id,timestamp

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Could you please tell me how are you fetching specific details from the tracker store. Elaborating my doubt below:

in my run_app.py (socketIO class) i have used mongotracker like this-

> db = MongoTrackerStore(domain=“d.yml”,host=‘host ip’, db=‘xyz’, username=“x”,password=“x”,collection=“x”,event_broker=None)
>
> agent = Agent.load(‘models/dialogue’, interpreter=‘models/current/nlu’,action_endpoint = action_endpoint,tracker_store=db)

now i want to fetch some data like db.sender_id or db.event. the reason of doing it is to store it column wise on my mongodb.Please help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This information should already be stored in your mongodb, so there should be no extra need for you to store it.
Maybe see the documentation for this https://rasa.com/docs/core/tracker_stores/ and make sure your `endpoints.yml` file includes the correct information:

```
tracker_store:
    store_type: mongod
    url: <url to your mongo instance, e.g. mongodb://localhost:27017>
    db: <name of the db within your mongo instance, e.g. rasa>
    username: <username used for authentication>
    password: <password used for authentication>
    auth_source: <database name associated with the user’s credentials>
```

For information on how to fetch specific details from your mongodb maybe have a look at the mongodb docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/.

Answer (score 0):

look at this Example
I am using Pymongo to connect monogoDB. try to understand my code

```
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List
from pymongo.database import Database
from pymongo import MongoClient
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker 
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
import pymongo
# url="http://localhost:3000/api"
client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db=client.sample
class mercdesCarAction(Action):
    def name(self):
        return "mercdesCarAction"
    def run(self,dispatcher,tracker,domain):
        res = db.datas.find({'action':'mercdesCarAction'})
        for i in res:
            dispatcher.utter_button_message(i['text'],i['buttons'])
        return []
```

Comment: While your example may be working it's better to spend some words explaining why your example is working so that other may find it more useful